# view controller issues in tab bar and side menu

Tags: ios

i just created tab bar controller with side menu i got output with black screen but i dont know how to assign two view controllers in app delegate please tell me how to make it work.i need that specific code to make it work.

```
//AppDelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong,nonatomic)UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

//AppDelegate.m

```
@interface AppDelegate ()<SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = window;

    self.tabBarController =[[UITabBarController alloc]init];




   //Initialize View controller and speciality

    UIViewController *viewcontroller1=[[HomeView alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller2=[[Speciality alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller3=[[Activity alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller4 =[[Notification alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller5 =[[Profile alloc]init];

   self.tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewcontroller1,viewcontroller2,viewcontroller3,viewcontroller4,viewcontroller5, nil];

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.376 green:0.729 blue:0.318 alpha:1.000];


    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];




    HomeView *frontViewController = [[HomeView alloc] init];
        RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

       UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
        UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];

        SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
                                                        initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];


        mainRevealController.delegate = self;

        self.viewController = mainRevealController;
        self.window.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];




        self.window.rootViewController =self.tabBarController;


        self.window.rootViewController=self.viewController;


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


        return YES;

}
```

Comment: I knwo you asked this question about 4 days ago, and I forgot to answer like I said I would, but check back when you have a minute if you have questions, you now have the full answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arun, I'm going to hook you up big time, if you change your library to JASidpanels, this is going to be easier for you and I already just made the solution. Download JASidePanels, use this library instead, it does the same thing as the one you have, but it's better, download here:

https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels

and if you don't want to worry about doing this yourself, here's the GISTs of the App delegate files:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e85536b17296287ec34f

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/93b620135418ddc8f1ed

Start the demo project, and then all you need to do is change the AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m files and you have exactly what you want, and more:

Here's the new AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "JAAppDelegate.h"

#import "JASidePanelController.h"
#import "JACenterViewController.h"
#import "JALeftViewController.h"
#import "JARightViewController.h"

@implementation JAAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.viewController = [[JASidePanelController alloc] init];
    self.viewController.shouldDelegateAutorotateToVisiblePanel = NO;

    self.viewController.leftPanel = [[JALeftViewController alloc] init];


    UIViewController *viewcontroller1=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller2=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller3=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller4 =[[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UIViewController *viewcontroller5 =[[UIViewController alloc]init];

    viewcontroller1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    viewcontroller2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    viewcontroller3.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    viewcontroller4.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    viewcontroller5.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];



    UINavigationController *navcontroller1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller1];
    UINavigationController *navcontroller2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller2];
    UINavigationController *navcontroller3=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller3];
    UINavigationController *navcontroller4 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller4];
    UINavigationController *navcontroller5 =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller5];


    viewcontroller1.title = @"one";
    viewcontroller2.title = @"two";
    viewcontroller3.title = @"three";
    viewcontroller4.title = @"four";
    viewcontroller5.title = @"five";

    navcontroller1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam"];
    navcontroller2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam"];
    navcontroller3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam"];
    navcontroller4.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam"];
    navcontroller5.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cam"];

    self.this = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    self.this.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navcontroller1,navcontroller2,navcontroller3,navcontroller4,navcontroller5, nil];

    //self.this.tabBar.barTintColor =  [UIColor orangeColor];
    self.this.tabBar.backgroundColor =  [UIColor orangeColor];


    self.viewController.centerPanel = _this;
    self.viewController.rightPanel = [[JARightViewController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Here's the new AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class JASidePanelController;

@interface JAAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) JASidePanelController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *this;


@end
```

This works, here's proof:

[image]

[image]

[image]

this all works, you can customize the sides a very easily, and this doesn't break nearly as much as the other sidepanel controllers. Ask questions if you have them!

ALSO, make sure you add your own custom images to the tabs. This works without a hitch and you will now have yourself a very very robust navigation system that works prostyle. In fact, this JASidePanels is probably one of THE most popular amongst production apps because it doesn't cut corners and doesn't break the guy who made it is a very very good at what he does. Also, this took me about 10 minutes to make and this is just the start, you can do a lot more with this little side panel library than the others. This library literally requires 4 files, that's it, no mess, no fuss, no stupidity.

Comment: hahaha, no problem, I told you last week it was easy but I forgot! And you can reuse this and do all sorts of stuff with it, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have privilege to comment on your code. 
So I am posting it in your answer.

Why did you set the  window's root view controller twice in your code, it will always be one.

Either this,

```
      self.window.rootViewController =self.tabBarController;
```

Or this,

```
      self.window.rootViewController=self.viewController;
```